# LXDE Desktop shortcuts layout configuration files

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am working on Lubuntu 14.04 LTS with LXDE Desktop Manager and I would like to change default Desktop icons layout. (These are shortcuts for some application).

By default, these icons are layered at the Top Left, and that is not what I want.

As I have dozens of box to configure, I was wondering whether a configuration file for this setting may exist. I can click and move icons where I want, but I am looking for an automatic setup. I would like for instance to move them at the Bottom Left.

I have been looking at ~/.config/libfm/*, ~/.config/openbox ...

Without any success.

Thanks for any tip

Comment: Thanks for the +1; I would prefer any kind of remark/help/hint/tip :/